# Any cocos2d-X functionality to share on facebook/send mail?

Tags: c++, ios, ipad, cocos2d-x

I have a nearly finished app, at the gameover screen I have a share button to share your score on facebook, or send it on email, is there a way for this in cocos2d-x?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, but there's no reason you can't call out to system APIs that provide such features. Look into [`UIActivityViewController`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIActivityViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html).